# Creating a loop that toggles a value and stores the new value for further computations

Tags: c, if-statement, toggle, bit-manipulation, sensors

Im trying to create the following loop :

```
int temp=0x07;

if(left sensor detects){
byteTx((temp)^(1<<0)); //(toggle bit 0)
}

if(right sensor detects){
byteTx((temp)^(1<<2)); //(toggle bit 2)
}

if(front sensor left || front sensor right detects){
byteTx((temp)^(1<<1)); //(toggle bit 1)
}
```

However, every other if statement will toggle the correct value but reset the others (because temp is 0x07).

Question : How can I make sure that I only toggle the bit needed, and keep the others unchanged even if they were toggled by the other if statements. Basically I want to store the outputs and use that instead of temp.

Thanks for the help, if you need more info let me know.

*edit*

Thanks for the responses but im not asking how to toggle, I'm asking how can I make sure that the value toggled is consistent between the IF statements.

0x07 will keep resetting the other bits that are toggled in other IF statements, I want to make sure that the IF statements do not reset the other bits.

Example

0000 0111 ^(1<<0) means the output is 0000 0110

but then if for the other IF statement :

0000 0111 ^(1<<2) means the output is 0000 0011

as you see the result is 0011, which will turn the 0 bit in the first statement back to 1.

how can I prevent that ?

Comment: By toggle, you mean clear? 'cause toggle would be `byteTx((temp)^(1<<0))`

Comment: Sorry I changed the code last minute, yeah its toggle ill fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to temp to hold the toggled bits after toggleing, you must modify it, by writing the new state back.
soemthing like

```
if(left sensor detects){
   temp=(temp)^(1<<0); //(toggle bit 0)
   byteTx(temp);
}
```

at the end of the loop, `temp` will have all the toggled bits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int temp=0x07;

if(left sensor detects){
    temp ^= 1<<0;
    byteTx(temp); //(toggle bit 0)
}

if(right sensor detects){
    temp ^= 1<<2;
    byteTx(temp); //(toggle bit 2)
}

if(front sensor left || front sensor right detects){
    temp ^= 1<<1;
    byteTx(temp); //(toggle bit 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XOR (`^`).

Bitwise XOR with 0 to keep the old value
Bitwise XOR with 1 to toggle the old value

```
oldvalue ^ 0x01 /* toggle bit 0 */
oldvalue ^ 0x02 /* toggle bit 1 */
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XOR operator « ^ ».